# Is list.clear() working backwards too?

Tags: java, list, for-loop, hashmap

Some weird problem.
I have a for loop which gets draw numbers from list and arranges them in pairs. I want a hashmap that would store paris and drawing number, so;

there's a list containing: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
for loop starts here,
1: 1 and 2
2: 3 and 4
3: 5 and 6
4: 7 and 8

that's what I've created;

```
List<Integer> numbers = new List<Integer>;
HashMap<Integer, <List<Integer>> parimap = new HashMap<Integer,<List<Integer>>;

for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        int firstinpair = numbers.get(0);
        int secondinpair = numbers.get(1);
        numbers.remove(0);                       //so it won't repeat
        numbers.remove(0);                      
        int pairnumber=i+1;
        temporary.add(0,firstinpair);
        temporary.add(0, secondinpair);
        pairmap.put(pairnumber, temporary);
}
```

And what I get is:

```
{1=[5, 2, 6, 4, 8, 3, 1, 7], 2=[5, 2, 6, 4, 8, 3, 1, 7], 3=[5, 2, 6, 4, 8, 3, 1, 7], 4=[5, 2, 6, 4, 8, 3, 1, 7]}
```

I've tried like this:

```
temporary.add(firstinpair);
temporary.add(secondinpair);
pairmap.put(pairnumber, temporary);
temporary.clear();
```

And then:

```
{1=[], 2=[], 3=[], 4=[]}
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.
Please help!

Comment: You are only creating *one list* as adding a reference to that list repeatedly. I suggest creating a list for each value of the map you want to add.

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept!

Comment: Could you provide more help for my additional question (see comment under your answer please). THX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you keep adding the **same** list object to your map within your loop. So all map keys point to the **same** value (`pairmap.put(pairnumber, temporary);` is  the culprit here).

Instead: create a *new* list `temporary` during each loop iteration; and then put that list into your map!

Besides: you might want to improve your *naming*. You see, `temporary` says *nothing* about the thing that this variable denotes. And then variable names should go camelCase, as firstInPair is kinda easier to read.

Finally: there is *no* point in removing the elements from that list - instead of always fetching the first two elements, you could simply do two calls using `get(i)` resp. i+1. It doesn't really matter in your small example, but for "real world" scenarios: removing the *first* element in an ArrayList is the *most expensive* operation that you can perform on such lists!

And as said; you absolutely do not need to do that. Your solution is more complicated (harder to read/understand) and more expensive at run time!

Comment: Thanks! It totally works!
About naming: it's just for the question. I had to replace names in my language for something that everyone could understand. But thanks for good tip!

Comment: Anyway I still can't understand why the list contains elements which had been removed with .clear() method??

Comment: Problem is: the source code you are showing ... is kinda incomplete. If you are really interested in solving that puzzle, step 1 is to put up a **real** working  [mcve] that shows the problem. The code that you have currently there ... doesnt even have a call to clear in that loop!

Comment: Sorry I mean why after .clear() on the list, same list is empty in the hashmap?

Comment: I thought it will be:
list.add, list.add -> adding list to hashmap -> list.clear()
But it works like (more or less):
list.add, list.add -> list.clear() -> adding list to hashmap -> list.clear()

Comment: As said: when you add **the** same list multiple times, you end up with the same list. That is why you need different lists; and then you dont "clear" anything any more.